# How to convert a website created in Dreamweaver to mobile site?

Tags: dynamic, mobile, static, web, dreamweaver

I developed a website full of JavaScript and all other dynamic stuff. I want to convert this website to mobile site using Dreamweaver or any other tool. Is that possible or I have to create mobile site for the same website from start?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Dreamweaver's Media Query feature. It will allow you to set up different style sheets for different sized screens. See the docs or Adobe's Dev Center for tutorials on how to use Media Queries.

Best - Joe